# Deep copy interconnected objects with references to each other

Tags: python, graph, reference, deep-copy

I have a graph data structure `Overlay`, which consists of instances that are interconnected by edges. Instances are represented by a set of `Instance`-objects and edges are represented by a set of `Edge`-objects. 
For convenience, each instance keeps track of the in- and outgoing edges by pointing to the corresponding existing `Edge`-objects. Similarly, each edge points to the source- and the destination-`Instance`-object.

For example, an overlay may consist of an instance `i1` that is connected to another instance `i2` via an edge `e1`. `e1.source` is a reference to `i1` and `e2.dest` is a reference to `i2`. `i1.edges_out` contains a reference to `e1`, etc. Overall, there are just 2 `Instance`-objects and 1 `Edge`-object.

I want to deep copy an overlay, in order to modify it (its instances and edges) without affecting the other overlay(s). My problem is that I don't know how to preserve the structure of interconnecting references as described above.

I use `new_overlay = copy.deepcopy(old_overlay)` and override `__deepcopy__` in `Overlay`, `Instance`, and `Edge` as follows:

In `Overlay`:

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memodict={}):
    new_overlay = Overlay(self.template, set(), set())  # new, empty overlay
    new_overlay.instances = copy.deepcopy(self.instances, memodict)
    new_overlay.edges = copy.deepcopy(self.edges, memodict)
    return new_overlay
```

In `Instance`:

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memodict={}):
    # new instance with same attributes
    new_instance = Instance(self.attributes)
    # edges_in, _out should contain references to the existing edges, not new objects
    new_instance.edges_in = copy.deepcopy(self.edges_in, memodict)
    new_instance.edges_out = copy.deepcopy(self.edges_out, memodict)
    return new_instance
```

In `Edge`:

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memodict={}):
    # new edge with same source and destination: these should be references to existing instances, not new objects
    new_edge = Edge(copy.deepcopy(self.source, memodict), copy.deepcopy(self.dest, memodict))
    new_instance.attribute = self.attribute  # no need to deep copy
    return new_edge
```

I was hoping for `copy.deepcopy` to take care of everything by using the `memodict`, but it doesn't work: When checking the object-`id` with the PyCharm debugger, the references in the copied overlay are sometimes incorrect. Instead of referencing existing objects, e.g., existing instances as source/destination of an edge, new instance objects are created.

How can I deep copy `Overlay` while preserving the structure of references? Both edges should have references to instances (source/destination) and instances should have references to edges (edges_in/edges_out).

Comment: Could you post the minimal necessary code to reproduce the problem please ?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45357443/7076615.   Basically, if you follow those templates, it just works!   Also, if you want; if you already have `__setstate__, __getstate__` implemented for pickling.  Guess what, to deep copy, you just pickle then unpickle the data.   I know that pickling works 100% for your tangled object reference graphs, and I've forgotten over time if deepcopy can handle it.